# How do I use preg replace to remove this?

Tags: php

I have a string `$test='23487°';`

How can I remove all the instances of the little circle that appears in the string using preg replace?

What to I enter for the regex to remove it?

EDIT - as Pekka says, str_replace is better I am now using that.  But the little circle is still not recognized by PHP...

Comment: `str_replace()` will do the job. No need for `preg`

Comment: @David19801 Are you viewing the output through a browser? Make sure the degree symbol (circle) is actually a degree symbol and not `&deg;`

Comment: Correct Mike, it was showing as symbol but I found it in source as #174 and str_replaced on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need regex, just [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$test = str_replace('°', '', $test);
```

The first parameter is the search term – the bit that will be found. The second parameter is the replacement string – the text that will be inserted instead. A blank string means "replace it with nothing", i.e. "remove it". The third parameter is the string on which to operate.

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to recognize the little circle character (temperature symbol)...

Comment: SOLVED: Was showing as degree symbol on page, but was &#176 in source.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
$test = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $test);
```

this will replace all your non ascii characters from your string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use preg_replace, you can do it like this:

```
$test = preg_replace('[°]', '', $test);
```

Also, for reference, here is a great site to test your regex:
http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php